How to solve this kind of set of two equations?
I am trying to rederive results of this paper. Free version here.
We have a set of two equations, Eqs. (58a, 58b):
$$
H_1Q_1+H_2Q_2^* = Q_1\omega \tag{58a}
$$
$$
H_1Q_2+H_2Q_1^* = -Q_2\omega. \tag{58b}
$$
$Q^*$ means conjugate. All $H_1$, $H_2$, $Q_1$, $Q_2$, and $\omega$ are $2\times 2$ matrices. Matrices $H_1$ and $H_2$ are known with values
$$
H_1 = \begin{bmatrix} A & D \\ D & A \end{bmatrix} \quad ; \quad H_2 = \begin{bmatrix} C & B \\ B & C \end{bmatrix}. \tag{55}
$$
Matrix $\omega$ is a diagonal matrix:
$$
\omega = \begin{bmatrix} \omega_\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \omega_\beta \end{bmatrix}.
$$
And matrices $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are:
$$
Q_1 = \begin{bmatrix} Q_{11} & Q_{12} \\ Q_{21} & Q_{22} \end{bmatrix} \quad ; \quad Q_2 = \begin{bmatrix} Q_{13} & Q_{14} \\ Q_{23} & Q_{24} \end{bmatrix}. \tag{56}
$$
We want to calculate $\omega_\alpha$, $\omega_\beta$, and all $Q_{ij}$. The authors of that paper gave solution in Eqs. (59, 60). The $\omega_\alpha$ and $\omega_\beta$ are:
$$
\omega^2_\alpha = (A-D)^2-(B-C)^2 \tag{59a}
$$
$$
\omega^2_\beta = (A+D)^2-(B+C)^2 \tag{59b}.
$$
$Q_{ij}$ are also given there.
Could someone please nudge me in the right direction? How do they arrive at this solution?

What does $Q^*$ mean? Conjugate or conjugate-transpose?

@Pranay star means conjugate only.

Each of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ can be thought of as consisting of 4 unknowns, so you have a total of 8 unknowns (and two more for $\omega_a$ and $\omega_b$).
If the entries of equations 58a and 58b are written out, and we treat the two unknown $\omega$s as constants for a moment, we get a total of 8 equations (one for each entry of a 2x2 matrix in each of the two equations) in the 8 unknowns. The unknowns (the entries of the $Q$ matrices) appear linearly, i.e., we have things like $AQ_{11} + ...$; no exponents, etc.
From this, one can write down an $8 \times 8$ matrix $J$ with
$$
J \pmatrix{
Q_{11}\\
Q_{12}\\
Q_{21}\\
Q_{22}\\
Q_{31}\\
Q_{32}\\
Q_{41}\\
Q_{42}} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0}.
$$
The entries of $J$ are combinations of $A, B, C, D$ and the $\omega$s.
In general, a linear system like this will have only the trivial (all zero) solution, and for that solution, any choice of $\omega$s will work, not just those offered by the authors.
For certain values of the $\omega$s, the matrix $J$ will have a nontrivial kernel. I'm guessing that if you wrote it out and did row-reduction on it, it'd rapidly become clear which values might work. (Then again, it could also be a complete mess).
One thing that puzzles me is that once you've found the $\omega$ that make the system singular, and find a vector in the kernel (i.e., find the entries of the two $Q$ matrices), any multiple of that vector will also be in the kernel, so I'm not sure how the authors give formulas for the $Q$ matrices.

+1. About the $Q$’s: After taking a look at the linked paper, I see that $Q$’s are supposed to encode a Bogoliubov transformation of creation/annihilation operators in a quantum system. Usually, such transformations are supposed to be unitary or something like that. I’m guessing that’s what fixes the normalization of the $Q$’s. The OP should have more insight into this, so he can confirm if this is indeed the intent.

I figured it was something like that, but didn't have the time/energy to look at the paper.
